# Android Box crash, how to restore /data files

Tags: internal-storage, termux

I have an Android box that has the app Termux (command line app) and in there I have some node apps made by me that are important.
I have screw up my Android by modifying the `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` file in a way that Android doesn't like it (I was being to creative with it :/ ). So now my Android doesn't boot.
I'm wondering if there is a way to restore my node apps now that my Android doesn't boot.
My android box is a Mini M8S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an male to male usb cable and the Amlogic Burning Tool to flash a new .img to my box.
That was the only solution that I came accross. And I lost all my node apps.